# Cannot overwrite dataframe column from another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ where I receive intervally some data like the ones presented below (one row every 3"):

```
CPU   Memory  Disk
 22       30    31
 25       33    29
 28       33    27
 25       32    30
 33       32    25
```

I have a dataframe called `dataset` that has three columns; namely `CPU`, `Memory`, and `Disk` where I store the data received from the RabbitMQ.
After the data are stored to the dataframe an `scikit-learn` algorithm is called (`DBSCAN`) and creates clusters of the data. `DBSCAN` stores the cluster of each data in an array called `labels_`. I then store the `labels_` into a new dataframe called `labels_df` in a column named `'Label'`.

What I want, is to create a new column named `'Label'` in the `dataset` dataframe and store the data in the `Label` column from the `Label` column in the `labels_df` dataframe.

My problem is that this `self.dataset['Label'] = labels_df['Label']` throws this error:

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`
The length of both datasets are the same at all times.

I get the abovementioned error only when I use the RabbitMQ. For instance, if a have a `csv` file and I store it into the dataframe and then create this extra column, everything works unproblematically.

Comment: try this dataset['Label'] = labels_df['Label'].fillna('')

Comment: I still get the same error... And its quite annoying, because if I do the same process on batch data, everything works. What I've noticed is that the first time I receive data from the RabbitMQ it works. It throws the error on the second time I receive data that is, when it needs to overwrite to the `dataset` dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to my problem. Turns out that all I had to do is to pass the `labels` in a new Dataframe called `self.labels` and concat it with the `self.dataset` dataframe. This is what finally happened:

```
self.dataset: 

   CPU Memory Disk
0   33     67   64
1   28     47   67
2    9     23   23
3   10     18   18
4   48     56   62
5   39     60   62
```

```
self.labels:

    Labels
0       -1
1       -1
2       -1
3       -1
4        0
5       -1
```

and the final dataframe is this one:

```
self.final_dataframe

   CPU Memory Disk  Labels
0   33     67   64      -1
1   28     47   67      -1
2    9     23   23      -1
3   10     18   18      -1
4   48     56   62       0
5   39     60   62      -1
```

If anyone finds a better solution please, do help!